# Issue with Laravel on Kubernetes: Environment Variables not Applied

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-rds, amazon-eks

I've deployed Laravel on Kubernetes and set up environment variables using Kubernetes Secrets. The environment variables include RDS credentials. When I inspect the container, I can see that the RDS credentials are correctly populated from the Secret.However, when I try to access any API endpoint, I encounter the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from 'users' where 'email' = jhon@gmail.com)
```

**Background:**

- I can access RDS from my server using the RDS endpoint, username, and password.

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxxxxxxx:/ecom-prod$ mysql -h ecom-db-identifier.xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u root -p
Enter password: xxxxx
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 113
Server version: 8.0.35 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2024, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| ecom               |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.29 sec)

mysql> use ecom
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_ecom         |
+------------------------+
| activity_log           |
| comments               |
| failed_jobs            |
| migrations             |
| password_reset_tokens  |
| permissions            |
| personal_access_tokens |
| policies               |
| users                  |
+------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.28 sec)

mysql>
```

- The database and tables exist, and I can query data from the database using terminal commands.
- When I check the connection configuration using php artisan tinker, I get the expected database configuration.

**Steps Taken:**

1. Successfully accessed RDS from the server using MySQL CLI.
2. Confirmed the existence of the database and tables.
3. Verified that data can be retrieved from the database using php artisan tinker.

**Expected Behavior:**
I expect Laravel to use the environment variables provided by Kubernetes Secrets to connect to the RDS database successfully.

**Actual Behavior:**
Despite the environment variables being correctly populated in the container, Laravel seems to be using default database configuration, leading to a "Connection refused" error.

I can read data from the database using `php artisan tinker`. For example:

```
> App\Models\User::find(1);
= App\Models\User {#5534
    id: 1,
    name: "Test User",
    email: "test@example.com",
    #email_verified_at: "2024-03-12 15:52:14",
    #password: "y$.bHDGgvm4zY.ucub4L.avOcERJzaS72sC0GZna6cAhy2/3xI1Cr/e",
    image: null,
    #remember_token: "SnA9FiQFl8",
    created_at: "2024-03-12 15:52:14",
    updated_at: "2024-03-12 15:52:14",
  }
```

**Additional Information:**
I created a test route and added the following code in the controller to check the database configuration in the browser:

```
\DB::connection(config('database.default'))->getConfig()
```

Surprisingly, this returns the default database configuration from config/database.php, indicating that Laravel is not picking up the environment variables set by Kubernetes Secrets.

```
{"driver":"mysql","host":"127.0.0.1","port":"3306","database":"forge","username":"forge","password":"","unix_socket":"","charset":"utf8mb4","collation":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci","prefix":"","prefix_indexes":true,"strict":true,"engine":null,"options":[],"name":"mysql"}
```

**Question:**
Why is Laravel not using the environment variables provided by Kubernetes Secrets for database configuration, and how can I resolve this issue?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a caching issue. Try running `php artisan optimize:clear` and try again.

Comment: Thanks, @EyadBereh for replying to me. It was a conflict between ``.env`` and Kubernetes ``secrets`` we should use one of these two. If we use ``.env`` with ``secrets`` then Laravel take ``.env`` first

Comment: You're more than welcome. I'm glad you could solve this problem.
And thanks for sharing the solution, because I'm working on AWS and I may need this one day.